# Asymptotic behavior of moments of log zero-truncated Poisson distribution as intensity goes to infinity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Let $N$ be a [zero-truncated (or positive) Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-truncated_Poisson_distribution) whose pdf is
$ \mathbb{P}\left\{N=n \right\} = \frac{\lambda^n}{(e^{\lambda}-1)n!}$.
Then what is
$$
\mathbb{E}[\log N]\quad\text{ and }\quad\mathbb{E}[(\log N)^2]?
$$
If it is impossible to express in closed form formula (like infinite sum), then can we express their asymptotic formula as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$?

This question is originated from my research: developing an Ito process for Poisson intensity $\lambda_t$.
To make $\lambda_t>0$, I consider geometric Brownian motion: $d \log \lambda_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t $, and to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$, first I need $\mathbb{E}[\log N]$ and $\mathbb{E}[(\log N)^2]$. Since there is no textbook or papers related to this topic, I have no idea how to handle this.

Thanks,

Comment: I assume that you can express these quantities as infinite sums. What type of formulae would you like to have?

Comment: If it cannot express in the closed form, I want to have asymptotic expression when $\lambda$ goes to infinity to show consistency of my estimator.

Comment: The variance is wrong. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-truncated_Poisson_distribution

Comment: Using this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1061289/312 I get $$E[\log N] \to \log(\lambda) - \frac{1}{2\lambda}$$

Comment: The quantities will be entire functions in $\lambda$. You may use ideas presented here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.iii to obtain the asymptotics of these functions for large positive $\lambda$. I am expecting that $$
\mathbb{E}\left[ {\log N} \right] \sim \log \lambda,\quad \mathbb{E}\left[ {(\log N)^2 } \right] \sim   (\log \lambda )^2 
$$ as $\lambda \to +\infty$.

Comment: Gary's asymptotics above (and probably also mine) are not enough to estimate the variance, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1061289/312), for a smooth function $g$ and a random variable $X$ with mean and variance $\mu,\sigma^2$ we can  approximate:

$$E[g(X)] \approx g(\mu) + \frac12 g''(\mu) \sigma^2 $$

$$E[g^2(X)] \approx g^2(\mu) +  g''(\mu)\sigma^2 + [g'(\mu)]^2 \sigma^2 $$

$$Var(g(X)) \approx  [g'(\mu)]^2\sigma^2  $$

(which might be regarded as a linear approximation of $Var(aX) = a^2 Var(X)$)

The mean and variance of a [truncated Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-truncated_Poisson_distribution) are

$$ \mu= \frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$
$$ \sigma^2= \mu (1 + \lambda - \mu)$$

Then, letting $Z=\log N$, for large $\lambda$:

$$E[Z] \approx \log(\mu) - \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \mu^2}\approx \log(\lambda) - \frac{1}{2\lambda} $$

$$Var(Z) \approx \frac{\mu (1 + \lambda - \mu)}{\mu^2} \approx \frac{1-(\lambda+1)e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}\approx \frac{1}{\lambda} $$

(this looks a bit sloppy, more careful analysis of the higher-order terms should be done, but  the asymptotics seems to be correct - cf eg [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6218120_Stochastic_processes_defining_sensitivity_and_variability_of_internally_calibrated_quantitative_NASBA-based_viral_load_assays))